# How to add permission on JAXB bean attribute

Tags: web-services, rest, jaxb, jersey, jersey-client

I have a Category object , which has three fields (catname,price,emailId) and in my application some user has access to view price and some don't have , i am not sure how i can add some annotation or somthing else which checks user permission and don't allow jaxb to add that attribute in xml .
below is my class
@XmlRootElement(name = "Category")
public class Category
{

```
@XmlAttribute  
private double price;  
@XmlElement  
private String catname;  
@XmlElement  
private String emailId;
```

.....
.....
}

I was thinking to add some annotation which check user permission and trigger to jaxb to not add that attribute in xml.
Please help me.

Comment: You may be interested in the `@XmlObjectGraph` extension we have in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy): http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/moxys-object-graphs-inputoutput-partial.html

Comment: Sorry it doesn't solve my purpose.